# Constant initialization in a dynamic way

Tags: c++, constant-expression

I think that the the variable declared as `const` applies only `Static Initialization`. I've written the following:

```
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream>

struct A{ };

const A *i = new A();

int main(){ }
```

and it works fine.

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/IIzumd)

But I expected that the the code is invalid because `new A()` is a `new-expression` and it is not a `constant expression`. Actually:
 sec. 5.19/2 N3797:

> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the
>   evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9),
>   would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>   [...]
>   — a new-expression (5.3.4);
>
> [...]

and

> A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression
>   whose value refers to an object with static storage duration or to a
>   function,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you probably meant `A * const i` (a constant pointer to `A`) and not `const A * i` (a non-constant pointer to `const A`).

Still, even with this modification, it is perfectly legal to initialise a `const` variable with a value that is not a constant expression (such as a value computed at runtime). However, it is then not possible to use such a variable inside constant expressions. If you tried that, the constant expression definition would kick in and you'd get an error.

Comment: Does it mean that const variables does not require a Static Initialization?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Yes, that's what I meant. *Some* `const` variables can also be constant expressions, but they don't have to. That's one of the reasons why C++11 introduced `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

The initialisation of a `const` variable does not require a constant expression.